# Python: How to use a list comprehension here?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have data of the following form:

```
foos = [{'bar': [{'baz': 1}, {'baz': 2}]}, {'bar': [{'baz': 3}, {'baz': 4}]}, {'bar': [{'baz': 5}, {'baz': 6}]}]
```

I want a list comprehension that will yield:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this. This sorta works:

```
>>> [[bar['baz'] for bar in foo['bar']] for foo in foos]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

but I want the results to be a flattened list.

Comment: To flaten the list : sum( [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] , [ ] ) There are two arguments for sum()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will do

```
 [y['baz'] for x in foos for y in x['bar']]
```

If you think it's not really natural I agree.

Probably explicit code would be better unless there are other reasons to do that.

Comment: " it's not really that natural" . Why ? What else on earth ?

Comment: @eyquem: I for example would find more natural swapping the two `for`s, but anyway once a comprehension becomes not trivial to understand then I think it's missing its target (in python readable code is the priority in the syntax). I assumed it was not trivial also for the original poster because he wouldn't have asked here in that case...

Comment: It is tempting to swap them because it seems more natural that the y in "for y in x['bar']" comes just after and nearby y['baz'] . But the iteration on x must be before the iteration on y because the interpeter reads the instruction from left to right and he must have met x before y to know what to do when he meets x in "for y in x['bar']"

Comment: @eyquem: I think it's unnatural because in the first expression (the one being interpolated) you see all variables, then in the second one you see none (it's the "outer loop") then in the third (the "inner loop") you see one var and so on. Counting the number of visible variables in each expression you get N, 0, 1, ..., N-1. I'd say it's more reasonable N, N-1, N-2, ..., 0. For the common case of single-variable list comprehension of course there's no difference. In other words it's like a "nested for" sequence where you however write **first** the innermost expression.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of nesting list comprehensions, you can do it with two `for .. in` clauses in one list comprehension:

```
In [19]: [item['baz'] for foo in foos for item in foo['bar']]
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that

```
[... for foo in foos for item in foo['bar']]
```

translates roughly into

```
for foo in foos:
    for item in foo['bar']:
        ...
```

Comment: I find that example pretty hard to read. The translated version is pretty straight forward, but condensing it makes it hard to tell what's going where.

Comment: @chmullig: I agree that multiple `for .. in` clauses are a little mind-boggling. But, a light-bulb went off (or was lit?) in my mind when someone here on SO explained how to roughly translate them, as I tried to show above. I hope it helps others as it has helped me.

Comment: FWIW, I find the comprehension quite 'comprehensible'. ;)

Comment: @chmullig It's the same problem when one studies the comprhension lists for the first time. With practice, it finally enters in the brain.

Comment: 6502's solution and unutbu's solution are identical, but the former has 3 points and the latter has 8 points at the present moment i write !

Comment: @6502 Thank you. I didn't know the Matthew effect. It ressembles a story about the subprime crisis. By the way, i find this fact deplorable for rational individuals as are supposed to be developpers. And for equity, I'll upvote your answer, 6502;

Comment: @eyquem: We're rational but also animals. Also may be that if there's such a general "brain offset" there's a good reason for it. On meta there has been some discussion about this "problem" of SO and possible solutions (e.g. hiding rep until you vote). I've seen cases in which what was IMO a bad answer got a lot of upvotes, and **better** answers not being upvoted... while the problem with identical answer is "objective" I think those cases are more important. Anyway seems the consensus among high-reps on meta is that this is not a problem, and being high-reps they're probably right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
foos = [{'bar': [{'baz': 1}, {'baz': 2}]}, {'bar': [{'baz': 3}, {'baz': 4}]}, {'bar': [{'baz': 5}, {'baz': 6}]}]

for x in foos:
  for y in x:

    for i in range(len(x[y])):
      for z in x[y][i]:
        print x[y][i][z]
```